# Using Keras for sklearn AdaBoost with a custom Y parameter

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, adaboost

I am trying to apply AdaBoost to a Keras model. The thing is that I have to use a custom loss function (unscaled deviance) which works well when I am using Keras into the RandomizedSearchCV of sklearn, but when I try to use AdaBoostRegressor i get :

```
ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (64501, 2) instead.
```

This error is coming from the fact that in my custom loss function, I use three arguments. However Keras only accepts two parameters (y_true, y_pred), so I bypassed this by passing a tuple with two values instead of y_true, like this :

```
#Loss function     
def deviance(data, y_pred):
    y_true = data[:, 0]
    d = data[:, 1]
    
    lnY = KB.log(y_true)
    bool1 = KB.equal(y_true, 0)
    zeros = KB.zeros_like(y_true)
    lnY = KB.switch(bool1, zeros, lnY)
    
    lnYp = KB.log(y_pred)
    bool2 = KB.equal(y_pred, 0)
    zeross = KB.zeros_like(y_pred)
    lnYp = KB.switch(bool2, zeross, lnYp)
    
    loss = 2 * d * (y_true * lnY - y_true * lnYp[:, 0] - y_true + y_pred[:, 0])
    return loss
```

So the program takes the tuple (call it 'feed') and unpacks it in order to calculate the unscaled deviance. I then use it like this and it works :

```
grid = RandomizedSearchCV(pipeline, cv = cv, param_distributions=param_grid, verbose=2, n_iter = 40) #plus de folds pourraient augmenter la variance
grid.fit(data, feed)
```

But now, I want to use this keras model in an AdaboostRegressor by using :

```
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, RandomizedSearchCV
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

def baseline_model2(dropout = 0.2, kernel_initializer = 'glorot_uniform', nn1 = 15, nn2 = 10, lr = 0.001, act1 = "relu"):
    with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
        # create model
        #building model
        model = keras.Sequential()
        model.add(Dense(nn1, input_dim = 21, activation = act1, kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer))
        model.add(Dropout(dropout))
        #model.add(Dense(2, activation = "exponential"))
        model.add(Dense(nn2, activation = act1))
        model.add(Dense(1, activation = "exponential", kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer))
        optimizer = keras.optimizers.adagrad(lr=lr)
        model.compile(loss=deviance, optimizer=optimizer, metrics = [deviance, "mean_squared_error"])
        return model


clf = KerasRegressor(build_fn=baseline_model2)

from sklearn.ensemble import AdaBoostRegressor
boostedNN = AdaBoostRegressor(base_estimator=clf)
boostedNN.fit(data, feed)
```

It is this part that gives me the ValueError. I know it comes from the fact that I am supplying a tuple to the algorithm, but I am searching for a way to bypass this, because Keras will need that tuple in order to evaluate the deviance correctly. I think editing a line or two in skl library could do the trick but I didn't manage to find the right place to do it by myself.